# Python Regex Select Element

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I've got an array with elements which are different names such as and

[abc, def, agh § dsd, sdse, 12a § asd].

I would like to select only those that have § in it and erase the other elements from the array.

The names change in length and also the position of § in the name changes.

Does anybody have an idea?

Mine was

```
    names = [re.findall(r'(?<=>)[^><]+(?=<)', str(i).strip()) for i in select('§')]
```

However, my regex skills are below zero...so...help is much appreciated!

Comment: You want to erase the elements that have `§` in it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the elements are strings, `[name for name in names if not '§' in name]`